# converting json file to csv in Python - TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm trying to convert a json file to csv. I got stuck at the following problem: I want to extract data from the undersection "snippet".

I was trying the following script, but it returns the error: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import json

with open('input1.json') as json_data:
data = json.load(json_data)
for r in data ['items'] ['snippet']:
    print (r ['kind'])
```

And here is a part of json file:

```
{
"kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
"etag": "\"gMxXHe-zinKdE9lTnzKu8vjcmDI/a3mLolGMIuGWUS6prd_fSkWBK8c\"",
"pageInfo": {
"totalResults": 1,
"resultsPerPage": 1
},
"items": [
{

"kind": "youtube#video",
"etag": "\"gMxXHe-zinKdE9lTnzKu8vjcmDI/Dv8RZiEKwUBsQIzhG2G0UrgyGKA\"",
"id": "FiZlVR7UxiQ",
"snippet": {
"publishedAt": "2016-09-07T14:12:12.000Z",
"channelId": "UC8_MMK_ePSIQf0cRvX63RkQ",
"title": "Babusia - RODZINA PIRATÓW odc. 04 (PL)",
"description": "Rodzina piratów to serial animowany opowiadający o rodzinie       
piratów, która mieszka na wyspie wraz z innymi mieszkańcami. Co dzień  
pirat Wiktor Mac Bernic poszukuje skarbów, które są ukryte na wyspie.    
Jednak przeszkadza mu w tym jego sąsiad Albert Derekin wraz z jego  
rodziną. Na dodatek jego syn jest zakochany w Krewetce, czyli córce 
Wiktora.",
"thumbnails": {
"default": {
"url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/FiZlVR7UxiQ/default.jpg",
"width": 120,
"height": 90
},
```

So the question is, how to extract the itemsfrom the section 'Snippet' in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`items` is a list; you're trying to access a field in the list, instead of an element of that list.

It's nested as so:

- dict list dict dict

but you're accessing it as if it was structured like this:

- dict dict list dict

Here's one way of doing it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import json

with open('input1.json') as json_data:
data = json.load(json_data)
for r in data ['items']:
    snippet = r ['snippet']
    print (snippet ['kind'])
```